# Any good c++ library for web programming?

Tags: c++, web

I searched the web, and found cgicc, rudeserver and Wt etc., but none of them suit my needs. I want a library that can parse all the request data to a get,post,cookie and file array, just like php does.

- Cgicc etc use formentry to get form data, but it's way too difficult to use.
- Wt use the widgets to develop, which I think is not very comfortable.

I used to use PHP for web programming, but when I know that C++ is amazingly faster than php, I decide to use C++ instead.

Any suggestions? thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you come to that conclusion that "C++ is amazingly faster than PHP"?

Comment: check out this benchmark [link](http://gwan.com/imgs/gwan_all_hello.png)

Comment: @user2758004 C++ is not listed on that benchmark.

Comment: @cdhowie oh, your are right, then check this [link](http://blog.famzah.net/2010/07/01/cpp-vs-python-vs-perl-vs-php-performance-benchmark/), besides, i thought c++ are as fast as c.

Comment: @user2758004 C++ is a different language than C.  In some respects, performance is comparable.  In other respects it is not.  Also, your focus on benchmarks is a bit premature.  Do you anticipate your application having hundreds of thousands of concurrent viewers?  Is the extra development time spent in C++ (compared to a higher-level language) worth less than the cost of a few extra application servers?  If the answer to either of those questions is "no" then raw performance is not what you should be concerned with.

Comment: @cdhowie yeah, i did hesitated, php is very easy to get hands on, and i developed a few projects, and it runs well. But recently i want to gain more power of programming, and found that c++ is more powerful. the performance advantage is appealing. It may take more time to develop as you mentioned, but i thought i can deal with this  by creating some good libraries, the over all time will be dramatically reduced.

Comment: I use cgicc with C++ as the back end for a web page, works quite well.

Comment: @nemasu really? i just tried cgicc yesterday, but found it difficult to use, as i use jquery and ajax frequently, it's not find to process data as forms, like  form_iterator name = cgi.getElement("name"); , i want something like get_data(); post_data(); etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand why [Wt](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt) don't fit. (you could use Wt without its "widgets", just for the HTTP aspect).

You could make a [FastCGI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FastCGI) application (it would fit nicely into many existing web servers).

You could also embed an HTTP server inside your C++ application, using some HTTP server library like [libonion](http://coralbits.com/libonion), [libmicrohttpd](https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/libmicrohttpd) or the one inside [poco](http://pocoproject.org/)

BTW, there are better alternatives to PHP like [Opa](http://opalang.org/), [ocsigen](http://ocsigen.org/), [kayalang](http://kayalang.org/) (without requiring C++).

Comment: yeah, i heard about these amazingly fast http servers, like gwan, moneky, cherokee and the ones you suggested. But i doubt about their reliability， nginx is still the most reliable choice for now.

Comment: may be you are right , i can just use the good parts of wt, but i prefer a library than can do some basic yet essential job, like parse query_string to a get_object, parse cin to a post_object, parse cookie to a cookie_object, that way i can gain more flexibility.

Comment: All the HTTP libraries I suggested can do that, and also FastCGI. And a web server supporting FastCGI (like `lighttpd` or `Apache`) would [re-] start the FastCGI process when needed.

Comment: ok, thank you Basile Starynkevitch, i will try.

Comment: i tried cgicc, but can not find a way to distinguish get_data and post_data, as i described in [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19088719/cgicc-cgi-getelements-get-or-post)