# No response on IE10 from a sample linux server in C

Tags: c, linux, internet-explorer, sockets

I am learning basic network programming using Sockets in Linux. I have written a sample program as below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#define SERVER_PORT 9000

unsigned int client_s;
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
unsigned int    server_s = 0;       ///server socket
struct sockaddr_in server_addr;     /// server address
struct sockaddr_in client_addr;     ///client address
struct in_addr  client_pi_addr;     /// client ip address

int addr_len;           /// internet address length

unsigned int    ids;        ///thread arguments

/// create a new socket
server_s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if( !server_s)
    return -1;

server_addr.sin_family  = AF_INET;      /// internet
server_addr.sin_port    = htons(SERVER_PORT);       /// host to network string : port 9000
server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);    /// listen on any (all) addresses, host to network long

/// bind it
if (bind(server_s, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) < 0 )
    return -2;

/// listen over it

if( listen(server_s, 100) < 0 ) /// 100 : backlog
{
    perror("Error in listen");
}

while (1)
{

    addr_len = sizeof(client_addr);
    client_s = accept(server_s, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, &addr_len);

    if(client_s < 0)
    {
        perror("Error accepting connection");
        exit(-1);
    }
    else
    {

        ids = client_s;

        char outbuf[128];

            strcpy(outbuf, "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nContent-Type:text/html\n\n");
            if( send(client_s, outbuf, strlen(outbuf), 0) < 0 )
                    perror("ERROR in send");
            if( send(client_s, "OKIE", 4, 0) < 0 )
                    perror("Error in sending oK : ");
        close(client_s);
    }   
}
close (server_s);
return 0;
}
```

Now, when I query using Chrome on IP:9000, I am getting the expected response as "OKIE" in the browser. 
But when I try to do same in Internet Explorer 10, there is no response. IE reports This Page can't be displayed.

Any explanation will be really helpful.

I am posting this question out of curiosity. Please feel free to close this questions if its a complete non sense :).

Comment: For one, maybe check the results of your api calls, like `listen()` for starters. `accept()` returns (-1) on error, by the way, and non-zero on success. Zero (0) is the *only* undefined return value, so it seems somewhat ironic it is the only one you're checking.

Comment: Changed the code as per your comments, but still no luck.

Comment: OK, I think I got it. Changed `char outbuf[128]` to `char outbuf[128] = {0}` and it worked now.

Comment: BTW even if it works I do not think that "OKIE" is a pretty valid "text/html" document

Comment: @trivalent that shouldn't make a difference. I believe your problem is you're slamming the door on your socket before the client can pull the data off their-side description. I'm fairly-certain you need a linger-state for this.

Comment: Did you consider using some HTTP server library? See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19087283/841108).

Comment: @Adriano It works with Chrome, but NOT with IE10.

Comment: @WhozCraig I am surprised to see it working with this little change. But the thing is only this change made it get working with IE10. Without it, I can only see it working with Chrome. And as there are no threads(?) involved in server side, I can't think of closing the connection earlier.

Can you please specify some area to look on?

Comment: @Adriano Ah.. I took you wrong at first. Can you please specify what should be the exact way to do this then?

Comment: Your client should get "text/plain" for a non HTML file. Usually it's not a problem because they simply render raw text when HTML isn't valid but some older versions of IE won't work with that (and actually it should be the right behavior). Wrap your "OKIE" within  "<html><body>OKIE</body></html>" (just for test purposes) or change MIME to "text/plain". That said you send a very minimal response (take a look with Chrome/IE to response header from any simple page).

Comment: Your first example didn't work because you send "garbage" to your client (strlen didn't find end of string then full buffer may be sent or even something _outside_ the buffer and it may even lead to an access violation). With proper zeroed buffer at least it'll get only what you supposed to send.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti, Kindly post your comment in answers so I can close  the question.

Comment: They're too sparse to put a decent answer together, feel free to post and accept your own answer with your final solution and all details you collected. I think it's an exercise many people will do!

Comment: :) In this case, I will accept wrim's answer. BTW, I only did what you suggested, and that solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like this is IE related issue - it just doesn't displays stuff, that does not have nicely done headers(i mean where not only Content-Type header is listed) and valid html("OKie" - is not a "Content-Type:text/html"). I think changing Content-Type to text/plain might fix it for IE.