# cgicc - cgi.getElements(), which method? get or post?

Tags: c++, post, web, get, cgi

cgicc can process form elements quite well , but how can i know whether the data is generated from get_method or post_method?

the piece of code i used:

```
cout << "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n";
try {    
    Cgicc cgi;
    const_form_iterator iter;
    for(iter = cgi.getElements().begin(); 
        iter != cgi.getElements().end(); 
        ++iter){
        cout << 
        "<table><tr>"   <<
        "<td>" << iter->getName() << "</td>"  << 
        "<td>" << iter->getValue() << "</td>" << 
        "</tr></table>" << endl;
    }
}catch(exception& e) {
    cout << e.what() << endl;
}
```

update:

i find this from the cgicc official page: "Parses both GET and POST form data transparently." (http://www.gnu.org/software/cgicc/)

it seems that cgicc don't want to separate get and post by design?

Comment: Did you look inside the [CGICC demos](http://www.gnu.org/software/cgicc/doc/cgicc_demos.html)?

Comment: yes, of cource, i check them again and again!

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch i may find the answer now, cgicc does not seperate get and post, but mix them. here is from the cgicc official page "Parses both GET and POST form data transparently." from [link](http://www.gnu.org/software/cgicc/)

Answer (score 1):

You can find the HTTP method (ì.e. `GET`, `POST`, etc...) of a request using [cgicc::CgiEnvironment::getRequestMethod](http://www.gnu.org/software/cgicc/doc/classcgicc_1_1CgiEnvironment.html#d170146297c55dbe990beb9beef34b18)

Comment: yeah, that may help a little bit, but still you don't know which of these data is from when you use both get and post.

Comment: for example: i post data(name=bob;age=12;) to the address localhost/main.cgi?app=main, cgicc will only generate mixed results from getElements, that is (name:bob;age:12;app:main)

Comment: Yes, but why do you care? You can ensure that all the names are different (because your CGI would also generate the form...)

Comment: post is more secure than get, i want to force the users to use post method in certain situation.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to solve it is by checking whether there is a variable name in the GET method query string that's the same name of the one in the POST method. This means that the variable name must be mentioned ONLY ONCE either of the two methods. In other words, if you combine the variables of the GET method with the variables of the POST in a single set, the variable name must be mentioned once in this set.